# firefox - follow link when in find mode

Tags: firefox

I'm on a page with a list of links.  I hit Ctrl-F to find the text I want.  The link I want to goto is now highlighted.  However, hitting enter does a find next instead of following the link.  Is there a keyboard shortcut to goto the link that is currently highlighted in find?
Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit the finder and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to the link.

Comment: Somehow this does not work for me... When I hit ctrl+enter in find mode, it toggles 'Highlight all'

Answer (score 7):

Press <kbd>'</kbd> (single quote) and the quick find bar pops up in "links only" mode so that only links are searched. Enter your search and hit enter to follow the link. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd> to jump to the next link containing your search term.

Found on the mozilla support pages [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-contents-current-page-text-or-links).

Answer (score 1):

This is super late but I hope it can be useful for future reader.

You can also:

- press `/` on the page
- scroll through the result using  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>
- press <kbd>Enter</kbd> once you find a link

This mode is pretty limited although but I am pretty happy not having to reach <kbd>Esc</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Chrome still does it best with using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to the link directly.